# What is the difference between _top and _self in HTML5?

Tags: html

HTML Links - The target Attribute
The target attribute specifies where to open the linked document.

The target attribute can have one of the following values:

- _self = Opens the linked document in the same window/tab as it was clicked (this is default).
- _top = Opens the linked document in the full body of the window.

Answer (score 0):

`_top` will make it escape from a possible frame, iframe or frameset. That is, it will replace the frame.